# Specified Tor exit node country produces wrong country?

Tags: tor

after specifying Tor exit node country , I get Netherlands instead of Italy.
That doesn't sound like normal behavior, anyone knows what could be the problem.

Configuration is Ubuntu 14.04 and Tor (apt-get) version 0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6).

Configuration file:

```
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
StrictExitNodes 1
ExitNodes {it}
StrictNodes 1
AutomapHostsSuffixes .onion,.exit
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 192.168.100.1 #(assuming this is the static IP address of the server)
DNSPort 9053
DNSListenAddress 192.168.100.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration isn't correct but Tor wasn't able to build a circuit using an exit node in Italy most likely because there isn't the capacity to.

As you can see from the data [here](https://compass.torproject.org/#?exit_filter=all_relays&links&sort=cw&sort_reverse&country=IT&exits_only&top=-1), there aren't many exits in Italy at all and they all have very low bandwidth capacity so your Tor client wasn't able to use any of them.

Some may not even be suitable for you depending on whether their exit policies allow what you are trying to access.